# Login Credentials to use when submitting App for review

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

This question is for anyone who has submitted an App to the App Store which integrates with the Uber API.  What login credentials did you use for submission? You real Uber account or a dummy one?

I'm not sure exactly what to do here.  I don't want to provide my real Uber login credentials for review.  Does Uber have some kind of dummy account that can be used for such cases?

Comment: I don't have an experience with Uber. But I'm sure that a dummy account would be more than enough. I have submitted apps to Apple which require Facebook login. And I don't even submit dummy credentials for those apps. I'm sure you'd be ok with dummy account.

Answer (score 0):

Uber doesn't provide dummy accounts. Instead, you could create a new Uber rider account, with a Visa gift card set as the payment method, that serves as a dummy account. Then, use the dummy account to make real (short) trips to build up your user history.

Comment: Thanks for your response and perfect timing, 'cos I literally just got a rejection notification from Apple a few mins ago saying they need Demo Account credentials to test the App.  Can this Demo account have history info?  That's one of the big things about my app.

Comment: I just went to the Uber Site right now trying to create a new account.  I don't see the option for to choose Gift Card as Payment method, it is asking for a Credit Card?

Comment: I just meant a Visa gift card.